# Set up LDTR to make Intel VT happy?

Tags: x86, kernel

I found this code in linux kernel (arch/x86/boot/pmjump.S)

```
# Set up TR to make Intel VT happy       
ltr %di                                //Here1

# Clear registers to allow for future extensions to the
# 32-bit boot protocol
xorl    %ecx, %ecx
xorl    %edx, %edx
xorl    %ebx, %ebx
xorl    %ebp, %ebp
xorl    %edi, %edi

# Set up LDTR to make Intel VT happy           
lldt    %cx                              //Here2
```

How those make Intel VT happy??
and
why those make intel vt happy??

thank you :)

Comment: I'm confused, if you found that code in the Linux kernel (and it works), what is the problem?

Comment: slugonamission//The problem is here1 and here2 how make Intel VT happy.

Comment: But I mean, are you asking how those statements work, or how to fix them?

Comment: i asking why those make intel VT happy. sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand it, they want a valid value in LDTR (NULL selector is valid). There are certain restrictions on the host and guest states during a switch between the two. Perhaps they want too avoid surprises there.